# How to install/start the new Windows 10 Edge browser?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, microsoft-edge

When I upgraded from Windows 8.1, I deselected the option to use Windows Edge as my default browser. Not only is Edge not my default browser, but it's not even installed! **How do I install/start the Edge browser?**

- I tried looking for the Edge App icon via the start menu and Cortana.
- There is a file `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe` but running it doesn't seem to do anything.
- Opening an HTML file brings up a dialog asking which browser to use (Edge is not an option)
- I'm not sure if Edge would be in the MS App Store, but I can't even find *that...*

**update:**

My default apps setting is missing both the "Edge" and "app in the Store" options:

[image]

Comment: what happens when u press windows button + R  then entering iexplore

Comment: @Botmaster: I clean installed Win 10, so I can't confirm now, but I think it just started Internet Explorer. I just tried now, and it opens IE with a big button to try Edge. Don't remember that after upgrading, before clean installing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got Microsoft Edge by doing a clean install of Windows 10.

- There is a giant 'e' Edge icon in the taskbar that wasn't there after the upgrade, just like [DavidPostill mentioned](https://superuser.com/a/949324/4390).
- The "Store" is right there next to it, too.

Something must have been broken during the last upgrade... it was time for a clean install, anyways.

Answer (score 19):

***How to reinstall the Microsoft Edge Browser***

I had faced similar issues with the edge browser. It disappeared one day. There was no way to manually launch the edge browser. I was able to fix it by reinstalling the edge browser.

First we need to delete the corrupt Microsoft Edge Folder. The path => C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe

Delete the "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe" Folder

You may not able to delete the folder itself and 2 or 3 files. but it does'nt matter. Select the folder, Hit Delete, Then if it asks for admin privileges, Just hit skip and then ok . Restart the computer.

Then Launch Powershell as administrator and run the following command. Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml" -Verbose}

Hit enter and once the command is executed, Quit powershell and restart the computer to complete the process.

The edge browser will be back and running in all its glory.

Please find below the link to the site that has step by step instructions to reinstall the edge browser
http://www.techtantri.com/how-to-reinstall-microsoft-edge-browser/

Comment: Links could evantually expires, provide a quoted context from the link.

Comment: Please explain what this means. 
 
 
'Links could evantually expires, provide a quoted context from the link'

Comment: i mean you should provide an answer, not a linking,  you are providen an step-by-step guide in a link, what happen with your answer it that link is broken in the future? your answer turns automatically in NOTHING, so if you want to give an answer provide all useful content in your answer as quoted from a reference. ;)

Comment: Thank You so much for the description. The solution I provided is complete in itself. However, the link is given for the not so techie guys who need to be hand held all the way.

Comment: This also worked to reinstall the Windows Store, I replaced Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge with Microsoft.WindowsStore and it got me my Store app back.

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I start the new Windows 10 Edge browser?

> To get going, select [image]on the taskbar.

Source [Get to know Microsoft Edge](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/getstarted-get-to-know-microsoft-edge)

---

#### How to set your default browser in Windows 10

> 1. Go to the "Settings" app
>
>    You've got a few options here. The easiest is to head to the Action
>      center and selecting "All settings." If you're on a device with a
>      touch screen, swipe in from the right. If you're using a mouse and
>      keyboard, click the Action center icon on the bottom right corner of
>      the taskbar, or press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to get there.
>
>    [image]
> 2. Goto "System", and then default apps
>
>    System is the option on the top left. Click (or tap) it, and you'll
>      see a few more settings. The default apps section is down near the
>      bottom of the column on the left.
>
>    [image]
> 3. Scroll down to Web browser, and make your choice
>
>    Web browser is down at the bottom of the list. Click it, and you'll be
>      able to choose from all of the browsers you've got installed.
>
>    And that's it. If you want to change the rest of your default apps,
>      you can do that here too. You can also choose the default apps for
>      particular file types, or particular protocols -- if you'd like to use
>      a particular app for any email address or map links you click, for
>      example.

[Here's how to set your default browser in Windows 10](http://www.cnet.com/news/heres-how-to-set-your-default-browser-in-windows-10/)

Comment: "I tried looking for the Edge App icon via the start menu and Cortana."

He already tried that

Comment: @kirill2485 He never said he looked on the taskbar ...

Comment: @DavidPostill: Thanks for the detailed step-by-step, but I think my problem is a little deeper than simply not being able to locate the proper control panel. I updated my question with a screen cap to clarify.

Comment: @Leftium Did you try the "Reset" button?

Comment: @DavidPostill: of course. It just resets it to no default app. (A blank square with a plus symbol in the middle.)

Answer (score 0):

For me, creating a desktop shortcut to `%windir%\explorer.exe shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge` worked. If you double-click on it, Microsoft Edge starts.

Comment: This just opens a file explorer window for me.

Comment: It opens a file explorer if you run it in Command Prompt. I actually created the shortcut on the Desktop and it worked.

Comment: @MC10: I tried creating a desktop shortcut and it did not work. After clean installing Win 10, I confirmed running that command from the run menu and command prompt starts MS Edge. It does not make a difference.